# Running PostgreSQL commands from anywhere on the terminal

Tags: postgresql, macos-sierra

First off, let me say that I'm new to both using Mac and PostgreSQL. I just installed Postgres using their installer and it was installed in /Library/Postgres/... when I tried running createdb from the terminal it returned an error `createdb: command not found`. I ended up using `/library/postgresql/9.6/bin/createdb` before I coud get it to work.
Here's my question, how do I set it so that I don't have to type in the full path again to use the `createdb` command.
I'd love a detailed explanation.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to execute the **psql** command to get into the postgresql interacive shell.

In your terminal:

```
psql
```

Postgresql interactive shell should start. In this shell

```
> createdb yourdatabasename;
```

Btw: If **psql** is not found you will probably need to add it to your path and restart your terminal, something like this with the path matching your machine:

```
export PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin:$PATH
```